# Building a tower out of unlimited blocks.

Tags: combinatorics

You want to build three towers. Each tower must be 200 feet high, and you can only use blocks that are 25 feet in length or 50 feet in length. How many different ways can you build three towers if you have an unlimited amount of bricks?

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that the towers are in a row, left to right, and *order matters*.

By rescaling, we may assume that the blocks have size $1$ and $2$, and we are building towers of height $8$.

If $a$ is the number of ways to build a single tower, our answer is $a^3$.
So now we find $a$.

Let $t_n$ be the number of ways to build a tower of height $n$. Then $t_1=1$ and $t_2=2$. Note that
$$t_{n+2}=t_{n+1}+t_n.$$
This is because if the bottom block of a tower of height $n+2$ is a $1$, the rest of the tower can be constructed in $t_{n+1}$ ways, while if the bottom block is a $2$, the rest of the tower can be constructed in $t_n$ ways.

Now compute. We have $t_3=2+1=3$, $t_4=3+2=5$. Continue until you find $t_8$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $b(n)$ be the number of buildings that are $n$ feet high.  Express $b(n)$ in terms of $b(n-25)$ and $b(n-50)$. Tabulate $b(n)$ for small $n$ and then work your way up to $b(200)$.